# Perform Linq Orderby generic list contain integer and string value

Tags: c#, linq

In my generic list contain integer and string value. how do i perform OrderBy or OrderByDescending.

For example

```
  List<String> codelst = new List<string>() { "1","2","3","4","5","10","100","a12","b12" };
  codelst.OrderBy(g => g);
```

**It shows like as follows**

```
1    
10  
100    
2    
3    
5     
a12    
b12
```

**but need to show**

```
1        
2    
3    
5    
10  
100  
a12   
b12
```

if I have convert to int it shows input string error

```
codelst.OrderBy(g => Convert.ToInt32(g));
```

How to achieve this

Comment: Use the overload of `OrderBy` that accepts an `IComparer`. Then implement the `IComparer` as you need it. For example, see [Alphanumeric/natural sorting in C# using IComparer](http://snipd.net/alphanumericnatural-sorting-in-c-using-icomparer).

Comment: @CodeCaster that's not a duplicate because this is about a mix of numbers and digits

Comment: @Dr.Snail It is also the solution for this question.

Comment: @MatthewWatson and 10 years later `[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]` is still the way to go?

Comment: @Dr.Snail Why wouldn't it be? After all, the CLR runtime classes use large amounts of the Windows API in their implementation - for example, OpenFile() - despite it being more than 25 years old... But yes, the answer is: It is still the way to go.

Comment: You can do this: `codelst.OrderBy(g => new Tuple<int, string>(g.ToCharArray().All(char.IsDigit)? int.Parse(g) : int.MaxValue, g))`. btw, I don't like the idea of using a `DllImport` for this; also no idea why this has been reported duplicate of a question which is asking for sorting a `FileInfo` array; although it has answers in non accepted answers, but still, it is weird.